# Mac OS .bash_profile errors

Tags: linux, mac, bash, terminal

I'm running Mavericks 10.9.5 and I have tried to install Metasploit from [this guide](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-framewor/).

It was until the Install Homebew I used

```
echo PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And now I get this error every time I open Terminal:

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/Renzo/.bash_profile: line 7: syntax error in conditional expression
-bash: /Users/Renzo/.bash_profile: line 8: syntax error near `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"'
-bash: /Users/Renzo/.bash_profile: line 8: `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"'
```

All commands seem to work just fine but the errors concern me. I have opened the .bash_profile before and deleted anything to do with rvm on all 'profiles' prior to this error but the errors are referring to the bash_profile. This is what the bash profile currently looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

[[ -s "$HOME/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I want this fixed as soon as possible so I can backup my drive for the first time using Time Machine and upgrade to Yosemite. There was a major vulnerability called Rootpipe that was allegedly fix for ONLY Yosemite 10.10.3 and not older firmwares but that was reportedly a failed fix by a former NSA staff a couple days ago.

Comment: One line with an extra trailing quote? This counts as too localized IMO and should be closed|deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This line has an extra single quote at the end. Take that off and try to source the file again. `source ~/.bash_profile`.

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"'
```

Comment: I don't see that error.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 5 and 7 are both bad
and should be <strike>deleted</strike> commented out
until/unless somebody can figure out what they are supposed to be.

- Line 5:

  ```
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
  ```

  simply expresses the *value* of `$PATH` as if it were a command. 
  Since that is not a valid command, it produces the first error:
  `No such file or directory`.
- Line 7:

  ```
  [[ -s "$HOME/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Nessus/run/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
  ```

  is an incomplete command.  `[[` should be paired with `]]`. 
  But appending `]]` to the line isn't the answer,
  since that would result in a statement that checks for
  the existence and size with a file with a name that is the value of `$PATH`
  (or something similar to it), which is a highly unlikely filename,
  and then doesn't do anything with the result of the test.